# Simulate running multiple server and client instances using Java concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server, java.util.concurrent

I want to simulate running of multiple servers and clients on a single machine.

I plan to create multiple threads of servers and clients using Java's concurrency package.

I will differentiate between servers and clients from each other and among them using only port numbers.

Say, I will have a series of 800XX ports for servers and 900XX ports for clients.

I need to know if what I am doing is correct. Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is correct. One minor comment is that the client ports can be automatically allocated by system.